# async call in Adomd.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ssas, adomd.net

I have an asp.net core (.net 5) project that I connected to SSAS and I use Adomd.net for connecting to SSAS(Tabular mode) Database

but I problem this library(Adomd.net) does not have any async functions

1- It does not have a problem that it does not have a async function ?

2- Is there another library for this that has a async function ?

3- There is a way I can call the functions of this library asynchronously ?

Adomd.net : https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.NetCore.retail.amd64/19.21.0

Answer (score -1):

You can write async/await methods on your own using TPL. Here is the [MS official](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl) docs link.
You can also wrap your Synchronous methods in Task.Run() and use async-await to achieve at some point, but yes there are caveats of using async-await as well, that need to be taken care of.